# Visual basic Passing values from last datagrid form and update it to new Form

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagrid, continuation-passing

I am having a problem with my code. The problem is I cannot fetch the ID.

Here is my code.

```
 Private Sub UpdatePurchase_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        txtID.Text = PassName
        txtName.Text = PassID
        cqty.Text = Passqty
        cucost.Text = Passucost
        ctotal.Text = Passtotal
    End Sub
    Private Sub Updatebtn()
        tqty.Text = Val(cqty.Text) + Val(qtyText.Text)
        tucost.Text = Val(cucost.Text) + Val(cucost.Text)
        ttotal.Text = Val(tucost.Text) * Val(tqty.Text)
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE tblPurchase SET itemQuantity='" + tqty.Text + "',UnitCost='" + tucost.Text + "',TotalCost='" + ttotal.Text + "'WHERE purchaseID='" + txtName.Text + "'"
        Try
            con.Open()
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Purchased Successfully Updated")
                cleartxt()
            End If
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: @cosmoonot I approved your edit. When editing, please also [remove things like "hi" and "thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333), don't add them.

Comment: Sorry sir...im kind a new here but ;ill keep that in mind ahaha

Comment: No problem, @Jovan Magalong! My comment was directed at another user, though. I addressed user cosmoonot, who [suggested an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15893335) to your question. I approved that user's edit, but also removed the "Thanks!" that he/she added. Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope you'll get a useful answer!